# please explain me HLSL VertexShder

Tags: directx

I'm using vs2015 and studying dx11.
I'll show you code first.

```
cbuffer cbperobject {
    float4x4 gWorldViewProj;
};

struct VertexIn {
    float3 Pos : POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;
};

struct VertexOut {
    float4 PosH : SV_POSITION;
    float4 Color : COLOR;

};

VertexOut main( VertexIn vin ) 
{
    VertexOut vOut;

    vOut.PosH = mul(float4(vin.Pos, 1.0f), gWorldViewProj);
    vOut.Color = vin.Color;
    return vOut;
}
```

This is my vertex shader code. I rahter copied it from internet.

```
HRESULT result;
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
XMMATRIX* dataPtr;
UINT bufferNumber;


// Transpose the matrices to prepare them for the shader.


// Lock the constant buffer so it can be written to.
result = mD3dDContext->Map(contantBuff, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
if (FAILED(result))
{
    return false;
}

// Get a pointer to the data in the constant buffer.
dataPtr = (XMMATRIX*)mappedResource.pData;

// Copy the matrices into the constant buffer.
XMMATRIX world = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mWorld);         // 버텍스의 월드변환
XMMATRIX view = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mView);       // 카메라
XMMATRIX proj = XMLoadFloat4x4(&mProj);       // 직교투영
XMMATRIX worldViewProj = world*view*proj;
worldViewProj = XMMatrixTranspose(worldViewProj);
*dataPtr = worldViewProj;

// Unlock the constant buffer.
mD3dDContext->Unmap(contantBuff, 0);

// Set the position of the constant buffer in the vertex shader.
bufferNumber = 0;

// Finanly set the constant buffer in the vertex shader with the updated values.
mD3dDContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(bufferNumber, 1, &contantBuff);

return true;
```

This is my setting constant buffer in shader code.

First, what is difference between POSITION and SV_POSITION semantic? Would you recommend good HLSL tutorial book? I'm Korean and I'm living in Korea. There is no good book in here; I don't know why, all good book is out of print. What a bad country for studying programming.

Second, why should I transpose my camera matrix(world*view*proj matrix) before CPU gives data to GPU? It's Vertex * matrix = processed Vertex. Why should I transpose it?

Comment: You don't need a book to learn shaders. There are plenty of tutorials out there on the internet, just google it. Besides, I would rather lean cross platform GLSL instead of platform specific HLSL

Comment: Thanks for the comment. What I really want is very detailed information about HLSL code like what's the difference between SV_POSITION and POSITION and if I designate register number how do I know how much register i have? like that.

Comment: You can find those information on the internet. Anyways, if you want a book then I would recommend Frank Luna's Introduction to 3D game programming with DirectX 12: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-DirectX-Computer-Science/dp/1942270062/ref=pd_bxgy_14_img_2/168-5145907-2184468?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=PJHRNTHVRR134THQ9WGN It's the best book out there for learning DirectX 12 and HLSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well  POSITION(Semantic)  gives  directive to GPU, that  concrete  values  will  be placed  as points  in coordinate space and  SV_POSITION  is  giving  directive for pixel  shader. Actually  it  gives  order  to  GPU about pixels  location on  screen mainly  in range -1 to 1.  Look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509647(v=vs.85).aspx

Well seems you  need  Linear Algebra  lessons mate.  Matrix  transposition is the key stone  in 3d graphics.  With  Matrix  transpositions(And same time  transposed  Matrix is  inverse Matrix and Inverse Matrix  is always Orthogonal)  all  Matrix Transformations  are  happening(Translation,  Rotation, Scaling).  First of  all  you  need  Linear  Algebra  stuff and  about  Rendering Api be it  OpenGL or  DirectX(never mind  they  are just API's) you can  grab  any  book or  online documentation you  can look  at  amazon.com.      Happy  graphics  coding pal ;).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. about math...  A = vertex  M = transformation matrix. C = transformed vertex.I know about linear algebra but I already know M then A*M =C isn't it? My question is why I need inverse matrix at first? not how to get inverse matrix

Comment: Vertex  Shader is marking  vertices by  GPU  in screen space(View space or  Camera space) which will be converted in  View  Frustum for  that  conversion Transformation  matrix is  essential.  :) .  When Vertex  Shader will  do  entire job, then GPU will order to Pixel  Shader to paint  your vertex  geometry with colours.

Comment: you know what, it's about how data are stored in matrix. if vector is row vector then  V*transpose M  = TV.  if it's column vector then M*V = TV.

Comment: people keep saying about inverse matrix. I wonder they know what the basis is and linear transformation.